# How to import .obj files in Google Sketchup?

Tags: import, sketchup

I would like to import .obj files into Google SketchUp with its textures, currently SketchUp only imports .3ds format.

The **current work flow** that I use is to **import the .obj file into 3D Max** and **export a .3ds file**. The problem is that the file **loses its textures** and all that I get in SketchUp is the model minus the texture.

Is there a free importer for .obj files in Google Sketchup or a free converter that can convert the .obj files to .3ds with the textures, so that I don't have to build the textures from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay got it [this post](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-864126.html) helped me solve the issue, it wasn't Google SketchUp's issue in importing the textures it needed to link up in 3d Max.

This is the text of the post that helped to solve the issue, just in case anyone else faces this problem. I merely followed these steps and the .3ds file imported perfectly textures et all into Google SketchUp:

> Make sure texture file need to be saved in same folder, as you already did.
>   And name of file better not longer than 8 letters.
>   There comes trick part, if you try to render the scene, an error pop out asking for missing texture.
>   Go to "Customize" - "configure user paths" - "external files" Tab, add the path of folder .3ds file saved.
>   It will appear in render.